# Eslint with standard and flow extentions doesn't work

Tags: node.js, eslint, flowtype, standardjs

Package devDependencies:

```
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
"babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
"eslint": "^5.9.0",
"eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^3.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
"eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
"eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
"nodemon": "^1.18.7"
```

.eslitrc file:

```
module.exports = {
  "extends": [
    "standard",
    "plugin:flowtype/recommended",
  ],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": [
    "flowtype"
  ]
};
```

.babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["flow"]
}
```

Sample js file from the project:

```
/* @flow */

module.exports = function (app, db) {
  test: string // The problem occurs here
  // More code below ...
}
```

The problem is linter gives messages in reference to "test: string":

> [eslint] Unexpected labeled statement. [no-labels]
>
> [eslint] Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. [no-unused-expressions]
>
> [eslint] 'string' is not defined. [no-undef]

I noticed that both extensions work fine separately. The problem occurs when I'm trying to use them both together like in .eslintrc file above.

Comment: you need to provide babel config. ordering matter: flow should strip type information out of the code first

Comment: `.eslintrc` should be without `module.exports = `